# Mobile nav menu left and right side

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I'm having some trouble figuring out my mobile nav. I have one on the left and one on the right, and they are supposed to slide out. The left one is working fine, but the right one just pops open, no transition.

I've been staring at the CSS for the past 4 hours, messing with some transitions. I'm not sure why it's not popping out smoothly, but everything else works.

Here's a jsFiddle with some code: http://jsfiddle.net/Etn6q/

I started out using this tutorial:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/15/off-canvas-navigation-for-responsive-website/

```
<div id="outer-wrap">
    <div id="inner-wrap">

        <div id="top_mobile_bar" class="clearfix">
            <a class="nav-btn" id="nav-open-btn" href="#nav">Menu</a>
            <a class="nav-btn" id="info-open-btn" href="#info">Info</a>
        </div>
```

And I have some styles in style.css and adjusted the mobile-flyout-menu.css. That's where I have all my transitions:

```
.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-ready #info .block {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;

    -webkit-transition:         opacity 300ms 100ms, -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay:   ease, 0s;
    -moz-transition:            opacity 300ms 100ms ease, -moz-transform 500ms ease;
    -o-transition:              opacity 300ms 100ms ease, -o-transform 500ms ease;
    transition:                 opacity 300ms 100ms ease, transform 500ms ease;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    -o-transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);

    -webkit-transform-origin:0;
    -moz-transform-origin:0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0;
    -o-transform-origin:0;
    transform-origin:0;
}
```

I'm not sure if that is the problem code. It could be the javascript, I attached that to my jsFiddle.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Antu, do you want something like when you click on menu its respective block will slide down and when you click on info its corresponding block will slide down is it? do you want int with css or jQuery is fine with you?

Comment: Hi Pravin, I have the menus set up to slide out, not down, but it pushes the main content (inner wrap) aside and shows up. My issue is with the right slide menu. CSS is preferable but jQuery is fine if it fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: well this maybe not exactly similar to your design but almost there - http://jsfiddle.net/nicooprat/Aahqh/ ans similar step by step tutorial - http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/create-quick-css3-only-menus-for-mobile/ Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm still having a hard time. I basically searching for the one clue as to how I can have my right #info div glide out like it's left #nav counter part.

Comment: I suspect it's the CSS but can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but I figured it out. For anyone who might stumble on this with the same question in the future, I had to split my JavaScript into two (main-L.js and main-R.js), one for the Left and one for the Right menu. I also had to add another wrap for the new JavaScript file to use. Basically I just added an R at the end of the classes that applied to my right menu in the js and CSS.

```
<div id="outer-wrap">
<div id="inner-wrap">
<div id="inner-wrapR"><!--added wrap here-->

    <div id="top_mobile_bar" class="clearfix">
         <a class="nav-btn" id="nav-open-btn" href="#nav">Menu</a>
         <a class="nav-btn" id="info-open-btn" href="#info">Info</a>
    </div>
```

This is the bit of CSS that I had trouble identifying that controlled the smooth animation. It was the #inner-wrap that needed styling, while I was trying to put the transformation on the menu itself.

```
     .csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-navR #inner-wrap {
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(-38%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
          -moz-transform: translate3d(-38%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-38%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
          -o-transform: translate3d(-38%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
          transform: translate3d(-38%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      }
```